# Cant get react native project to compile - can't resolve required file

Tags: react-native, compiler-errors

I have a simple project in the directory aaa.
My App.js file specifies

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,FlatList,Alert} from 'react-native';
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import {Asset} from 'expo-asset';
require ('mcf.db');
class App extends React.Component
{
}
export default App;
```

My metro.config.js has the following

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('@expo/metro-config');
const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
module.exports = {
  transformer: { 
    assetPlugins: ['expo-asset/tools/hashAssetFiles'],
  },
  resolver: {
    assetExts: [...defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts, 'db'],
  },
};
```

The file mcf.db is in my app directory (/home/mcf/aaa).

I start my project from the aaa directory
expo start

and try and run it in a web browser and get the error

web - failed to compile
/home/mcf/aaa/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'mcf.db' in '/home/mcf/aaa'

This has driven me berserk.
Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?
Why can't it see mcf.db ??

Comment: My  view is : one need to relative path here mcf.db, if not given RN will assumed default folder and that folder it doesn't mcf.db doesnt exist.

Comment: After a lot of experimentation I found that the require is looking in the assets directory, i.e. I needed to create that directory, and copy mcf.db there, and all is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you missed to add the relative path to your `require()`. If it is in the same folder as your `App.js` file you could just do: `require(./mcf.db)`.

Comment: I tried that also, to no effect. It works if I put mcf.db in a folder called assets in the top app directory.